# Wrong Entity Framework version in config files with 6.1 installed

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I created a project from template which included EF 6.0.

I then updated the nuget packages and EF 6.1.1 is installed.

However in web.config i still have this:

```
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```

All other dependent assemblies are updated correctly (i.e MVC e.t.c)

Should i have updated this myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the assembly version, and it stays at 6.0.0.0

Comment: You mean that it changes on major releases? (i.e. EF 7?)